# One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified while using the android mapbox navigation in Android 14

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker, mapbox-navigation

In Android 14 i am facing this issue
**One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts**

the block of code which is responsible for this

```
 private fun initNavigation() {
        MapboxNavigationApp.setup(
            NavigationOptions.Builder(this)
                .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
                // comment out the location engine setting block to disable simulation
                .locationEngine(replayLocationEngine)
                .build()
        )
```

**compileSdkVersion 34 

targetSdkVersion 34**

On  MapboxNavigationApp i am getting crash and getting the further error do anyone has any clue regarding this. I am not using any broadcast receiver

Comment: This question is 4 months old. I assume you have already solved the problem? The call to `registerReceiver()` is obviously being made internally by the Mapbox code and the only way for you to fix this problem is to update your Mapbox library version to a version where Mapbox has fixed this issue.